# SQLite transaction doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, transactions

I prepared 2 files, "1.php" and "2.php".

"1.php" is like this.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:test1');
$dbh->beginTransaction();

print "aaa<br>";
sleep(55);
$dbh->commit();

print "bbb";
?>
```

and "2.php" is like this.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:test1');
$dbh->beginTransaction();

print "ccc<br>";
$dbh->commit();
print "ddd";
?>
```

and I excute "1.php". It starts a transaction and waits 55 seconds.

So when I immediately excute "2.php", my expectation is this:

1. "1.php" is getting transaction and
2. "1" holds a database lock
3. "2" can not begin a transaction
4. "2" can not get database lock so
5. "2" have to wait 55 seconds

BUT, but the test went another way. When I excute "2",then

1. "2" immediately returned it's result
2. "2" did not wait

so I have to think that "1" could not get transaction, or could not get database lock.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it, SQLite transactions do not lock the database unless

- a. you make them `EXCLUSIVE` (they are `DEFERRED` by default), or
- b. you actually access the database

So either you explicitly call

```
$dbh->exec("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION");
```

or you make a write operation (`INSERT`/`UPDATE`) to the DB before you start to `sleep()`.

To cite the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) (emphasis mine):

> Transactions can be deferred,
>   immediate, or exclusive. **The default
>   transaction behavior is deferred.**
>   Deferred means that no locks are
>   acquired on the database until the
>   database is first accessed. **Thus with
>   a deferred transaction, the `BEGIN`
>   statement itself does nothing.** Locks
>   are not acquired until the first read
>   or write operation. The first read
>   operation against a database creates a
>   SHARED lock and the first write
>   operation creates a RESERVED lock.